# person left in one's care

Tags: word-request

I knew, and for the life of me, I don't remember.

What's the name for a person in one's care: a child left in nurse's care, the VIP for a bodyguard, the civilian in military escort, a pupil for the teacher, a tourist for the guide etc; the counterpart for *caretaker*?

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but you might like to note that's a non-standard use of idiomatic *for the life of me*. This (somewhat dated) phrase is used to in conjunction with some action you *can't* do, (and still would not be able to do **even if your life depended on doing it**). Thus, for example, *"I once knew this, but for the life of me, I **can't remember** it now"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point. It could be fixed by rewording to "I knew, but for the life of me, I can't remember now ..."

Comment: @Jay: Absolutely. I wouldn't ordinarily bother raising such a small "error" in the first place, and it's easily "fixed" as you suggest. But I still think it's a slightly dated usage anyway - so given OP's English is normally of such a high standard, it seemed worth flagging up these points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say that someone is your "ward" or your "charge", meaning that you are responsible for him. But more often today, I think we say, "The child was Bob's responsibility." Which of course is vague -- a person could have many sorts of responsibilities -- but it's usually clear in context.